# How to get the value (not the key) of a TypedChoiceField in django form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a django form with some TypedChoiceFields like this one :

```
Q1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=choice_parser, choices = Q1_CHOICES, label=Q1_TITLE, initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```

Here is my Q1_CHOICES :

```
Q1_CHOICES = (
    ("W", "Woman"),
    ("M", "Man")
)
```

My problem is in my view when I call this form when I want to get the answer of the user I only succeeded to get the keys (`W` or `M`) but never the values `"Man"` or `"Woman"`.
I used  `form.cleaned_data["Q1"]` to get the answers.

I know I could differiantiate them with "W" and "M" but for the other questions it is a big deal

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is the expected result, since that is how it is saved in the model. Is this a `ModelForm`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: I'm not using Models at all in this user story